# How to get the equations for Probability distribution function and Cumulative density function of a gamma distribution in scipy (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics, gamma-distribution

Just as we can write the CDF and PDF of a random variable X, following a normal distribution, with its parameters - **std and mean**  using scipy in the following manner:

```
from numpy import sqrt, pi, exp
mean, std = 295, 250

# defining Cumulative density function
def cdf(x):
    cdf_eqn = lambda t: (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((t - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))
    cdf = quad(cdf_eqn, -np.inf, x)[0]
    return cdf

# defining Probability distribution function
def pdf(x):
    return (1 / (std * sqrt(2 * pi))) * exp(-(((x - mean) ** 2) / (2 * std ** 2)))
```

How can I define the CDF and PDF of a **gamma distribution** in the same way above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do it:

```
from scipy.stats import gamma

mean = 259
std = 250

x = 100

alpha = ( mean / std)**2
beta = std**2 / mean


def pdf(x,aplha,beta):
  return gamma.pdf(x, a = alpha, scale = beta)

def cdf(x,alpha,beta):
  return gamma.cdf(x, a = alpha, scale = beta)
```

Comment: Are you sure that you can use the same gamma.pdf function to get the cdf of the gamma distribution?

Comment: @digital_hog thanks for the correction. Changed the .pdf to .cdf

Answer (score 1):

You can code the PDF and CDF according to the definition of the gamma distribution:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution

You can choose the alpha and beta parameters.
Alternatively, you can use the scipy.stats.gamma package.